# Calling Script.Require in Shape view returned from IResultFilter not working in Orchard CMS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm currently writing my own module that needs some scripts to be loaded on all pages, both on the front-end and the dashboard, where the user is authorized to edit content. I've written an implementation of the IResultFilter that adds a shape to the 'tail' zone in the site's theme.

The shape is added to the page correctly and all is OK except for one thing. In the same shape I'm also trying to call Script.Require on a few scripts that I've added to the ResourceManifest, but they're not being loaded in to the page.

```
@{
    Script.Require("OrchardTinyMce");
    Script.Require("jQueryColorBox");
}
```

If I place this same code in a view that's not rendered using my IResultsFilter implementation then they are added to the page. I'd rather keep this bit of code in it's current view though as two alternates further down the line which require the same scripts and I don't really want to duplicate it.

Does anyone have any ideas how I get the scripts to register? Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked out how to do this. I've just injected IResourceManager into my HtmlFilter and then added the scripts as follows:

```
_resourceManager.Require("OrchardTinyMce");
_resourceManager.Require("jQueryColorBox");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that isn't working in your view, but you could just use the resource manager to add those scripts from your filter:

```
_resourceManager.Require("script", "OrchardTinyMce").AtFoot();
```

Inject the resource manager as per usual:

```
private readonly IResourceManager _resourceManager;
public MyFilter(IResourceManager resourceManager) {
  _resourceManager = resourceManager;
}
```

Comment: We must have answered this at the same time! Thank for the answer though, it's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Haha yeah, looks like you actually got in there a few seconds before me! Glad you got it all working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want that other user or you can simple override this scripts (use lightBox insted colorBox). You can add your shape to Content Zone (but this shape shouldn't have output html).

```
Services.WorkContext.Layout.Content.Add(YourShape, ":after");
```

It works from IResultsFilter