# How to validate dates when creating in Orchard a custom query filter

Tags: c#, filter, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to create a custom filter form in Orchard with two fields: DateFrom and DateTo.
I'm able to create it with two textbox fields with the following code:

```
public void Describe(dynamic context)
    {
        Func<IShapeFactory, dynamic> form =
            shape =>
            {

                var f = Shape.Form(
                    Id: "EventRangeForm",
                    _DateFrom: Shape.TextBox(
                        Id: "DateFrom", Name: "Date From",
                        Title: T("Events from date"),
                        Description: T("Events from date"),
                        Classes: new[] { "text medium" }
                        ),
                    _DateTo: Shape.TextBox(
                        Id: "DateTo", Name: "Date To",
                        Title: T("Events to date"),
                        Description: T("Events to date"),
                        Classes: new[] { "text medium" }
                        ));
                return f;
            };

        context.Form("EventRangeForm", form);
    }
```

If possible I'd like to be sure that the user inputs a date with a specific format. In a view I usually attach a datepicker to the textbox, but here I'm not able to do so. Is there a solution more efficient than writing in the ApplyFilter method the whole code to validate any possible input that the user can write on the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DateTimeValidation : FormHandler {
   public override void Validating(ValidatingContext context) {
      if (context.FormName == "EventRangeForm") {
         var min = context.ValueProvider.GetValue("DateFrom");
         //validate...
         context.ModelState.AddModelError("DateFrom", "You did it wrong!");
      }
   }
}
```

You could create your own form view with client side validation and a pretty datetime picker. Or you could create a script that you include with the shape to change the textbox into a datetime picker via jquery?

Comment: Thanks! But how can I include a script in my IFormProvider? I tried with RegisterStartupScript but it didn't work.

Comment: Inject the resource manager and include your script from there. Check this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27020881/1037489

Comment: Thanks, I only have a remaining problem. Is it possible to have both the DatePicker and the Orchard tokenizer associated to the same field without conflicting? I tried to do it, they both display but I can't edit what I select from the tokenizer (i.e. for the querystring tokens) because the DatePicker blocks from writing alphabetic characters in the textbox.

Comment: I think you will need to write a very customized datepicker script for that, sorry